# Ubuntu 22.04.01 crashes in Firebird/Lazarus applications

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, lazarus

I develop applications in and for Xubuntu using Lazarus (2.2.4) and Firebird (2.5.9). I accidentally upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.01, and since then Ubuntu crashes when I use my apps. This happens in several different apps, and with apparently random triggers (although so far always starting with a left or right mouse click). When it happens, the screen goes blank and then reverts to the Ubuntu logon screen, losing all the old session. Sometimes after the blank screen the old session re-appears, but it is unstable and after only a few more mouse/keyboard clicks the session dies. The crash report in /var/crash suggests Xorg  is at fault. Any ideas please where I go from here, apart from downgrading back to Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: It's not much to go on I know. The PC is 15 years old so perhaps too old for U22.04? It has dual core pentiums, 4GB RAM,  & 8GB left on the hard drive, so ok in theory, and all working ok under U18.04 and U20.04. The Lazarus apps were originally built on a different PC (where they work fine), but clutching at straws I installed Laz on this PC and rebuilt them here, same result. The error initially does some limited garbling, eg all instances of "5" are displayed as ",", eg windows not completely closed, before crashing teh session at teh next mouse press.

Comment: I'm stuck as to further diagnostic steps, or ideas for a work-around apart from going back to U20.04, I'd be grateful for some help.